# how to make modular, oo "animations" with canvas / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, animation, canvas

I come from a flash animation background, and am learning to create animations with HTML5 `<canvas>` and plain JavaScript.

In flash, you can draw a `movieclip` and link it to an actionScript class file. This makes each movieclip somewhat OO / modular and allows you to more easily call and reference them in your app.

As JS has no native class support, and drawing with Canvas seems more rudimentary than in Flash, **what is an example of a way to structure your javascript for a large/complex canvas animation**?

Comment: I found the [starfield tutorial at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642499/Learn-JavaScript-Part-1-Create-a-Starfield) informative. But I do not claim any background to say if it fits your purposes.

Comment: @LutzL: exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you for sharing. +upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-class approach by using objects.

For example, if you want to lets say move a box across the canvas you define the box as an object and update it for each frame:

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LBNmK/)

```
function ooRect(x, y, w, h, color, dx, dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
}
```

Now `ooRect` is an object which you can update to move around and change color etc.

You can extend it with methods which makes it self-contained update-wise so it updates itself per frame:

```
function ooRect(x, y, w, h, color, dx, dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;

    this.update = function(ctx) {
        this.x += this.dx;
        this.y += this.dy;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
}
```

You can now have a "host" routine (or another special object) to update all your objects stored in the array:

```
var objects = [
        new ooRect(10, 20, 50, 70, 'blue', 2, 3),
        new ooRect(200, 300, 50, 70, 'red', -3, 2) /// etc.
    ];

(function loop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);  /// clear canvas

    for(var i = 0, o; o = objects[i++];)           /// update all objects
        o.update(ctx);

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);                   /// next frame
})();
```

Now it is a matter of implementing different types of shape objects with its properties and methods.

If you plan to use a lot of objects you can prototype them as that allow the browser to share code-base memory:

```
function ooRect(x, y, w, h, color, dx, dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;

}
ooRect.prototype.update = function(ctx) {
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect example, just the rundown on OO JS I wanted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Go with *requirejs* which is JavaScript file and module loader. 
http://requirejs.org/